How to update layers produced by QuickOSM map preset?
I have created an OpenStreetMap layer in QGIS by using the QuickOSM plugin like so:

Vector > QuickOSM > QuickOSM... > Map preset > select Urban > *set filter to "In: " > Run preset

This produced a road layer and a building layer.
Is there a way to update these layers without wiping them clean? I.e. maintaining the "sub-layers" (not sure if this is what it's called) such as Trunk, Primary road, Tertiary, etc, and their styling?

Export road layer to external geopackage: Export -> Save Features As..., add it to map.

Copy styles from road layer to new layer (urban-road) in example: Styles -> Copy Style -> All.. / Past Style (on new layer)

Right click on layer, Export -> Save as QGIS Layer Style File... and choose Save File: In datasource database:

Now you have data and style saved in one database. Run again QuickOSM, get new set of data and reexport newly downloaded road layer to the same geopackage. When asked, overwrite the existing layer:

Now you have data updated with old style read from geopackage file:

